# lightGBM classifier errors on class_weights

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I want to apply weights to my classes in lgbm (ie. manually force the model to prefer certain categories).  I can see what my categories are, but when I make a class weights dict using those categories the model errors with `ValueError: Class label [somevalue] not present.`

```
import lightgbm as lgbm
### Data prep
#[skipping as long & irrelevant -- only need to know classes for the question]#

### Get classes from data
model = lgbm.LGBMClassifier()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
model.classes_
```

gives:
`array([ 100.,  200.,  300.,  500.,  600.,  700.,  800., 1000.])`

apply the known classes to a class_weight dict as per [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.html#lightgbm.LGBMClassifier.predict)

> class_weight (dict, 'balanced' or None, optional (default=None)) –
>   Weights associated with classes in the form {class_label: weight}.[...]

```
model = lgbm.LGBMClassifier(class_weight = {100.:1,   200.:20,  300.:30,  500.:50,  600.:60,  700.:70,  800.:80,1000.:100} )
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

and we  get the error:
`ValueError: Class label 100.0 not present.`

error is repeated for the first element in the dictionary if we reorder or delete elements.

Comment: np.float64 in y_train, although they are floats representing integers for the problem I am currently handlings

Answer (score 2):

It looks like lightGBM doesn't take `class_label` values in the `class_weight` dictionary.  Instead, it places your labels in ascending order and you have to refer to them by index according to that order.

so

```
class_weight = {100.:10,   200.:20,  300.:30,  500.:50,  600.:60,  700.:70,  800.:80,1000.:100}
```

becomes

```
class_weight = {0:10,   1:20,  2:30,  3:50,  4:60,  5:70,  6:80,7:100}
```

and the working code is:

```
model = lgbm.LGBMClassifier(class_weight = {0:1,   1:1,  2:30,  3:50,  4:60,  5:70,  6:80,7:100} )
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

Which is a real undocumented doozy of a behaviour and makes the code quite hard to understand...

Can anyone confirm that this the correct intended behaviour?